# I need to show my name on a 7-segment character-by-character display

Tags: arduino

I need to display my name on a 7 segment display character by character, but I'm very new and don't have much idea where are the errors. Can anyone help me please?

I have made some changes like the X and Y constants or the if((digitalRead(bstart) == 1) && (digitalRead(bstop) == 0)) { part, but it still doesn't work.

[image: Image from Tinkercad, which is where I'm working from]

```
const int Y = 7;

const int DIGITOS[X][Y] = {
/*D*/ {1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
/*A*/ {1,1,1,0,1,1,1},
/*n*/ {0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
/*I*/ {0,0,0,0,1,1,0},
/*E*/ {0,1,1,0,0,1,1},
/*L*/ {0,0,0,1,1,1,0}
};
//const int OFF = LOW;

 int bstart = 3;
 int bstop = 2;
const int A = 4;
const int B = 5;
const int C = 6;
const int D = 7;
const int E = 8;
const int F = 9;
const int G = 10;

 
const int N = 7;
const int SEGMENTOS[N] = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G};

void setup()
{
  pinMode(bstop, INPUT);
  pinMode(bstart, INPUT);
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    pinMode(SEGMENTOS[i], OUTPUT);
    //digitalWrite(SEGMENTOS[i], OFF);//apagar
  }
}

void show(int d){
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    digitalWrite(SEGMENTOS[i], DIGITOS[d][i]);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if((digitalRead(bstart) == 1) && (digitalRead(bstop) == 0)) {
     for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
          show(i);
          delay(2000);//2 SEGUNDOS
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what errors? ...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to redefine 'print', which is already reserved (which you can tell because it changes color when you type it).  Try changing the name.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to renaming the 'print' function, you should change

> if(bstart == 1 && bstop == 0) {

to use the **digitalRead(pin)** function twice to actually read the pins and not only the integer variables (that don't change).

> if((digitalRead(bstart) == 1) && (digitalRead(bstop) == 0)) {

Comment: What print should i change the first one or the second one?

Comment: Both: where you define the function and where you use the function

Comment: ```void show(int d){
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    digitalWrite(SEGMENTOS[i], DIGITOS[d][i]);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if((digitalRead(bstart == HIGH)) && (digitalRead(bstop == LOW))){
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       show(i);
       delay(2000);// esperar 2000 milisegundos = 2 segundos
   }
  }
}``` like this?